# dropwizard no injection source found for a parameter error

Tags: dropwizard

I am new to Dropwizard i created a sample dropwizard maven project in eclipse followed this dropwizard tutorial [dropwizard tutorial](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html) . I am able to build the project however while running the project with command

> java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

it gives this error

> No injection source found for a parameter of type public dropWizardSample.Saying dropWizardSample.HelloWorldResource.sayHello(jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Optional) at index 0

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this error but I see a basic problem with the command you are executing:

```
  java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

should be

```
  java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server
```

Comment: the server needs a config as well to startup with

Comment: Config file is optional

Comment: i executed the command without config file as SaurabhNayar said but then it gave me "default configuration has an error: * template may not be empty"

Answer (score 0):

The complete command to execute should be

```
java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml
```

in which the parameters

`server` specifies you are trying to run an application and

`hello-world.yml` is the file where you specify the configuration for your application.

Comment: i had already tried executing using above command ,forgot to mention it in my question ....

Comment: understood the problem ... i was using Optional.java from wrong package it must be "com.google.common.base.Optional" instead of "jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Optional" i changed this and got the expected result ....

Comment: @kunal Good. By the way, what made you realize this was the cause?